# CSV database File Splitter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a DB file exported as CSV file

> [TABLE]
>   "Address"
>   [FIELDS]
>   "StreetNum","StreetName","AptNum","City","State","Zip"
>   [DATA]
>   6445,'High Land Rd',623,'Bloomington','IL',12345
>   [TABLE]
>   "VersionTable"
>   [FIELDS]
>   "TableName","MajVersion","MinVersion","UserID","Updated","Version"
>   [DATA]
>   'Macro',1,0,-1,'2009/10/24 10:23:17',0
>   'Personal',1,0,-1,'2015/10/24 10:23:17',0
>   'ProfileAccounts',1,0,0,'2016/10/26 11:22:21',2
>   [TABLE]
>   "Name"
>   [FIELDS]
>   "FirstName","LastName","MidName"
>   [DATA]
>   'Geo','Jones','L'
>   'Leo','David',''
>   'Neo','Stafford','K'

I need to Split it into filename as the Table name

Address.CSV

> "StreetNum","StreetName","AptNum","City","State","Zip"
>   6445,'High Land Rd',623,'Bloomington','IL',12345

VersionTable.CSV

> "TableName","MajVersion","MinVersion","UserID","Updated","Version"
>   'Macro',1,0,-1,'2009/10/24 10:23:17',0
>   'Personal',1,0,-1,'2015/10/24 10:23:17',0
>   'ProfileAccounts',1,0,0,'2016/10/26 11:22:21',2

Name.CSV

> "FirstName","LastName","MidName"
>   'Geo','Jones','L'
>   'Leo','David',''
>   'Neo','Stafford','K'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show the code where you are running into issues?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I need x" isn't a programming question, it's a job for a paid consultant.

Comment: I voted with TessellatingHeckler. At the same time, this is totally something you could do in PowerShell. I strongly urge you to try and figure it out, and come back for help if you get stuck, and provide what you've tried so far. Shoot, I'm sure you could find code that you could adapt from questions already answered here on SO (I know I've answered similar questions to split files, and convert things to CSV)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = Get-Content D:\test\originalFile.txt #file from question
foreach ($line in $file)
{
    #lines with description only start section and are omitted
    If ($line -eq "[TABLE]") { 
        $section = "file_name"
        continue
    }
    If ($line -eq "[FIELDS]") {
        $section = "field_names"
        continue
    }
    If ($line -eq "[DATA]") {
        $section = "data_in_fields"
        continue
    }

    if ($section -eq "file_name") { #one line with file name
        $filename = $line.Substring(1,$line.Length-2) + ".csv"
        Write-Host "filename :"$filename
    }
    if ($section -eq "field_names") { #one line with column names
        $fields = $line
        $fields | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\$filename 
        Write-Host "fields :"$fields
    }   
    if ($section -eq "data_in_fields") { #multiple lines with data
        $data = $line
        $data | Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\$filename
        Write-Host "data :"$data
    }

 }
 Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: Well shoot, if you're just going to hand them code at least make it interesting! `(GC TableDump.txt -raw) -replace "(?m)(?<=^|,)'(.*?)'(?=,|[\r\n]+|$)",'"$1"' -split '(?=\[TABLE])'|?{$_ -match '(?s)\[TABLE][\r\n]+(.*?)[\r\n]+\[FIELDS][\r\n]+(.*)'}|%{Set-Content -Value $($Matches[2] -replace '\[DATA][\r\n]*') -Path ".\$($Matches[1].Trim('"')).csv"}`